# Liquibase as an ant task: relative path to changelogs.xml not found

Tags: ant, liquibase

I use the 2.0.5 version of Liquibase to test database migrations. Currently, if I define the `changeLogFile` attribute into `updateDatabase` task as `<updateDatabase changeLogFile="${changeLogFile}"` and the `"${changeLogFile}"` is specified in `liquibase.properties` as `changeLogFile=com/db/master.changelog.xml`, the file `master.changelog.xml` will *not* be found.

I started an ant task using Eclispe and ant standalone.

So I use the following fix with `${basedir}/**src**/`:

```
<updateDatabase changeLogFile="${basedir}/src/${changeLogFile}"
```

But I would be very happy without such a dirty solution.

I try to specify the class path to XML files, using the /bin-directory

```
<fileset dir="bin">        <include name="**/*.xml" />    </fileset>
```

But a lot of exceptions occurred, so I commented out this block.

What did I do wrong?

The `liquibase.properties` file contains:

```
changeLogFile=com/db/master.changelog.xml
driver=org.h2.Driver
url=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/testhiberliq
username=sa
password=

#for diff between two databases
baseUrl=jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/testhiberliq
baseUsername=sa
basePassword=

dropFirst=false
tag=version 1.4
outputFile=outputFile.xml
outputDiffFile=outputFile.txt
```

---

The `NewFile1.xml` (used as `build.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="liquibase-sample">

    <property file="liquibase.properties" />

    <path id="lib.path">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    <!--    <fileset dir="bin">
            <include name="**/*.xml" />
        </fileset> -->
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="liquibasetasks.properties">
        <classpath refid="lib.path" />
    </taskdef>

    <target name="update-database">
        <!--       <taskdef name="updateDatabase" 
        classpathref="lib.path" />-->
        <updateDatabase changeLogFile="${basedir}/src/${changeLogFile}" driver="${driver}" url="${url}" username="${username}" password="${password}" dropFirst="${dropfirst}" classpathref="lib.path" />
    </target>

</project>
```

---

`master.changelog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<databaseChangeLog 
  xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/1.9
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-1.9.xsd"> 

  <include file="changelog/included.changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/> 
  <include file="changelog/included2.changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/> 
  <include file="changelog/included3.changelog.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/> 

</databaseChangeLog>
```

---

And the directory tree:

```
I:.
│   .classpath
│   .project
│   liquibase.properties
│   NewFile.xml
│   NewFile1.xml
│   outputFile.txt
│   outputFile.xml
│
├───.settings
│       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
│
├───bin
│   │   hibernate.cfg.xml
│   │
│   ├───com
│   │   └───db
│   │       │   master.changelog.xml
│   │       │
│   │       └───changelog
│   │               included.changelog.xml
│   │               included2.changelog.xml
│   │               included3.changelog.xml
│   │
│   └───testproject
│       │   Main.class
│       │
│       └───database
│           │   DatabaseDAO.class
│           │
│           └───pojo
│                   Users.class
│
├───lib
│       h2-1.3.168.jar
│       liquibase.jar
│
└───src
    │   hibernate.cfg.xml
    │
    ├───com
    │   └───db
    │       │   master.changelog.xml
    │       │
    │       └───changelog
    │               included.changelog.xml
    │               included2.changelog.xml
    │               included3.changelog.xml
    │
    └───testproject
        │   Main.java
        │
        └───database
            │   DatabaseDAO.java
            │
            └───pojo
                    Users.java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task will retrieve the changelog files from the classpath. You need to add the runtime root directory to the path as follows:

```
<path id="lib.path">
    ..
    ..
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
</path>
```

And alter the task as follows:

```
<updateDatabase changeLogFile="com/db/master.changelog.xml" ...
```

And the master changelog file also needs the full path the individual change files:

```
<databaseChangeLog .. 

  <include file="com/db/changelog/included.changelog.xml"/> 
  <include file="com/db/changelog/included2.changelog.xml"/> 
  <include file="com/db/changelog/included3.changelog.xml"/> 

</databaseChangeLog>
```

At runtime liquibase looks at the local directory or inside the jars and directories listed on the classpath.

Why this complexity? This approach enables the changelog files to be packaged as a jar archive, either separately or alongside your code. Very useful.

Comment: Hi Mark O'Connor, i have only xmls, that placed in class path, no jars with changelog xml exisit. If i try to set the "java" class path (aka "bin"), so a lot of exceptions will be thrown:Unable to obtain resource from i:\workspace\TestLqbsProject\bin\com\db\changelog\included.changelog.xml: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Comment: Hi Mark O'Connor again:-) The exceptions are occurred, if i used <fileset>-tag to retrieve the class path with changelog-xmls. I i use now pathelement with location "bin", so the liquibase ant tasks run!! Other changes don't needed. Thank you a lot for this replay